# React JS + .Net Core web API controller call issue on IIS server

Tags: reactjs, .net, asp.net-core, controller, iis-10

I have created react.js app in visual studio selection .net core web api with react template.

the template came with default page and tabs, home, counter and fetch data.
the application is running fine when i run from the visual studio local.

after that i configured IIS 10 with application pool and site
created a build and pointed my IIS to the build folder and start running the app

the app is launched file and working for the home page and counter pages

but, when i go to "Fetch Data" page it is throwing below error
`VM106:1  Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`

fetchdata.js file has below call to controller api

```
`  async populateWeatherData() {
      const response = await fetch('weatherforecast');
      console.log(response.json());
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ forecasts: data, loading: false });
  }`
```

```
Controller get method has :
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
```

I'm not sure if this is the issue of arry to json which is not able to process or anything more towards IIS side.

the app is running fine locally when i run via visual studio.

I have also installed :
Microsoft Run time installer
URL Rewrite Module 2.1
also, configured my web.config file

could you please help.

issue to fix the controller call in IIS for react js, .net core web api call

Comment: "pointed my IIS to the build folder" is wrong. If you follow the official tutorial, the right folder is the output folder of `dotnet publish`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#folder-contents